# how to delete Quotation mark from String nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string

I'm going to write the userid into the session, but when it's written, it gets 2 Quotation marks, e.g. "userid":""U386243148976"" I want it to contain only "U386243148976"

i console.log(userid) gets "U386243148976" but when writing to session it becomes ""U386243148976""

```
axios(userdata)
        .then(function (response){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.userid));
            userid = (JSON.stringify(response.data.userid));
            console.log(userid)
            return n = cb(null, {
                userid: userid,
                role: "editor",
              });
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
            });   
        });
      });
```

how to delete Quotation mark from String nodejs

Comment: Don't json stringify the userId or use a regex to replace the string

Comment: Where is `cb` defined?

Comment: This code I show only part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that `response.data.userid` is already a string?

If so, instead of

```
userid = (JSON.stringify(response.data.userid));
```

do

```
userid = response.data.userid;
```

Comment: i got it thank you so much, I'm a newbie to node.js and javascript.